# how to use shell's for loop to change two files

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, python

I would like to use for loop to create files in shell. 
I have 3 files named `sensor_1.nmf`, `sensor_2.nmf`, `sensor_3.nmf`, and I want to use a software to create another 7 python files for each files above,i.e.,
Using `sensor_1` creates 7 python files like `r_sensor_1.py`, `r_sensor_2.py` ...
My code is below:

```
for j in 1 2 3
do
    for k in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
        nacs2.2 -l nacs_mphs -m sensor_${j}.nmf -p r_sensor_${k}.py r_sensor_${j}_${k}
    done
done
```

But it can not work. Could somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Use bash -x to debug your code. Format your code better in your question. You are missing a do after your third line.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 0):

You can use brace expansion as opposed to iterating through the for loops.

```
nacs2.2 -l nacs_mphs -m sensor_${1,2,3}.nmf -p \
r_sensor_${1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.py r_sensor_${1,2,3}_${1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

Answer (score 0):

At your inner for-loop you are missing the "do".

```
for j in 1 2 3
do
  for k in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  do
     nacs2.2 -l nacs_mphs -m sensor_${j}.nmf -p r_sensor_${k}.py r_sensor_${j}_${k}
  done
done
```